# How does inheritance work when it comes to class methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

```
class SuperClass
  def self.superclass_method
    puts "I am the superclass method."
    puts "self = #{self}"
  end
end

class SubClass < SuperClass
end

puts SubClass.singleton_class.instance_methods.include? :superclass_method # true
puts SuperClass.singleton_class.instance_methods.include? :superclass_method # true
```

Both of these statements return true. Are there two copies of the same method?  One in SubClass' singleton class and the other in SuperClass' singleton class?

When running this code, I was expecting the second statement to return false because I thought ruby would be using the method that was defined in the SuperClass' singleton class.

How does this actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one copy of the method.

### Explanation:

#### 1. Singleton classes are instances

`SubClass` and `SuperClass` are both instances of `Class`. If you inspect the singleton class in IRB, you'll see something like:

```
> SuperClass.singleton_class
=> #<Class:SuperClass>
> SubClass.singleton_class
=> #<Class:SubClass>
```

The `SuperClass.singleton_class` is an ancestor of `SubClass.singleton_class` just the same way that `SuperClass` is an ancestor of `SubClass`. Said another way: classes are also instances (of Class), and work by the same rules.

#### 2. `instance_methods` takes an optional argument

These rules say that `SubClass.singleton_class.instance_methods` will return every instance method available, no matter which ancestor defines it. If you would like to only see instance methods defined on `SubClass.singleton_class`, you need to invoke `SubClass.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)`.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods

Comment: Yes, but the method appears to be in `SuperClass.singleton_class` and in `SubClass.singleton_class`. Why? Is it actually in both of these classes' methods table? Or is it only in `SuperClass.singleton_class` with a pointer from `SubClass.singleton_class`'s methods table to `SuperClass.singleton_class`'s methods table?

Comment: @AsadMoosvi updated the answer to include more information on `instance_methods`. Is that more helpful?

Answer (score 0):

```
class SuperClass
  def self.superclass_method
    puts "I am the superclass method."
    puts "self = #{self}"
  end
end

class SubClass < SuperClass
end

p SuperClass.singleton_class.instance_methods(false) # => [:superclass_method]
p SubClass.singleton_class.instance_methods(false) # => []
```

`superclass_method` is actually only defined in `SuperClass.singleton_class`. By default the argument to `instance_methods` is true and it shows methods defined in superclasses as well as methods defined in the class it's called on. By passing it the argument of `false` only shows the methods defined in that class.